# error with permissions when installing vue/cli

Tags: 18.04, nodejs

I have installed the latest LTS version of nodejs using the link doc from their website for linux_x64 (https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation)

The installation went well but when trying to install the vue/cli it gives me the error permissions.

```
 Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js' -> '/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/bin/vue'
```

The lib/node_module folder I have changed the owner:

```
sudo chown $USER -R /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/lib
```

because with the sudo i wasn`t able to install the vue:

```
sudo /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/bin/npm install -g @vue/cli
```

it give me :

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to create a sudo link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin/npx /usr/bin/npx
```

now is working fine :)